# Identify an 80's movie about a gun that makes people freeze in place

Tags: identify-this-movie

I feel like this is the only movie remnant from my childhood that I haven't been able to pin down. I have only vague memories from the movie, but what I recall is that it centers around a new technology that takes the form of a special gun that makes people freeze in place for several minutes, though if you're wearing mirror sunglasses then it won't work on you. There's a "good guy" and "bad guy" in the movie, the latter of whom is a burly guy with a mustache.

The only other thing I'm remembering about the movie is a scene where the good guy turns on a sink to wash his hands or something when the burly guy comes in, catching him off-guard and shooting him with the gun. The good guy then looks down and realizes that the sink is overflowing because it's been running while he was stunned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

This is [***Looker***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082677/) *(1981)*, written and directed by [**Michael Crichton**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Crichton).

> Looker’s most science-fiction invention is the **L.O.O.K.E.R. device** *(short for **Light Ocular-Oriented Kinetic Emotive Responses**)*, a “light gun” that stuns and paralyzes the target using light.
>
> **Anyone exposed to this weapon experiences a sort of “missing time” as they stand paralyzed**, allowing the weapon’s user to move around, invisible and undetected, for short periods.   [[Source](http://www.cyberpunkreview.com/movie/decade/1980-1989/looker/)]

**Overflowing sink:**

[image: Sink]

[image: Sink]

**Mirror sunglasses:**

[image: Glasses]

- The [**trailer**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4dTDm47Lms) doesn't feature the gun, but you can see it in action in [**this scene**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J8LYi16QIQ#t=00m22s).

Comment: P.S.: I made those screenshots from my copy.

Comment: thanks! I had completely forgotten that I posted this and a found it through yet another Google search. :) That is indeed the movie. With a 29% RT rating, it seems unlikely to be an amazing flick, but I might hunt down a copy anyway and give it a shot. Mystery solved!